# Bootstrap 3 - Wrapping row with collapsing containers

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble stacking containers that collapse. I have them set in a `row` with three columns of width 4. If another column is added, it's being pushed to the next row which is the desired behavior. But if I open the container about the newly started row, when it opens it pushes the newly wrapped container to the right, so the layout is now wrong. It reverts if you un-collapse the first row. Quick pictures below describe the situation.

Edit: The clearfix works great when the three columns are under the `col-md-4` setting. When it scales down to small size I have it set up for `col-sm-6`, and then the clearfix is making it so there are two columns, a row of one column, then the next row of three starts again. Any solutions to this or do I have to rethink my layout?

[image]

Comment: put the 4 column in a new row clearfix

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a clearfix element after the third element to fix this layout.

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

More information can be found here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets

Comment: Would all of the containers still be in one `row` element with a clearfix in between every three containers, or do they each get their own row?

Comment: You can do either, really. You could make 3 elements per row or you could make 1 row which has all the elements and a clearfix after every 3 elements,

Comment: This works great when the three columns are under the `col-md-4` setting. When it scales down to small size I have it set up for `col-sm-6`, and then the clearfix is making it so there are two columns, a row of one column, then the next row of three starts again. Any solutions to this or do I have to rethink my layout?

Comment: You need to make the clearfix visible only for that breakpoint. For example <div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>. You also need to set up a clearfix div every second element that is only visible in sm.

Comment: Great that sounds like a great fix. Thanks for your help.